# Pass JS value in php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

How can I send JavaScript variable value in php?

Like :

```
     for(var j=0;j<count_array_item;j++){
        get_item = <?php echo json_encode($cld[???]['title']); ?>;  //want to get 'j' value.
     }
```

Comment: Why dont you assign the whole  $cld array to js array and use that instead?

Comment: This is conceptually wrong. Even though you can achieve it, you will override get_item. You can use PHP iterations to render javascript with the proper info, which, as well, is a wrong approach. Better make your backend return the desired result and query it via ajax

Comment: An alternative approach:
var jsonStr = <?php echo json_encode($cld); ?>;
var data = JSON.parse(jsonStr);

Now you can manipulate any data from 'data' variable. It represents an array now. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code. `foreach` loop store the value in `js` `get_item` array.

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    var get_item = new Array();
    <?php foreach($cld as $val){ ?>
        get_item.push('<?php echo json_encode($val["title"]); ?>');
    <?php } ?>
</script>
```